# How should I config nginx.conf to be able to output cookie USER_ID in access.log file?

Tags: nginx, logging, webserver

I have default nginx setup on mac OS - just nginx itself and basic static page that I serve using nginx. I put manually USER_ID cookie in browser and I want to have it in my access.log file. This is just task for training purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the variable $cookie_USER_ID in you log format directive.

For ex:

```
log_format combined '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$cookie_USER_ID"';


access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined;
```